# Render a Panorama with Room Outlines with panorama camera

Tags: panoramic

I have a simple room, a camera inside and a Panorama-Camera for creating a 360° Panorama Render. That works fine.

I want to have only the outlines of the room-walls (and later stuff like a table inside) rendered like comic-style. I tried different technics like freestile and Line Art, but they have limitations and none of them works in panorama-camera only in perspective and eevee randerer.

is there any solution for this problem in Panorama-Camera?

Comment: are you really sure that freestyle line art doesn't work in panorma-camera? i didn't try out but i cannot believe...

Comment: yes, its written in the manual of blender